# Doing the following operations in a for loop in R: reading files, assigning column values, and merging files

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a bunch of files that all consist of two columns, an identifier and some value for a certain trait:

```
ID,score
1,.02
2,.04
4,.03
... etc
```

I want to do the following 3 operations on these files:

```
# 1: read in the file
MyData_trait1 <- read.csv("datafile_trait1.csv",header=T,sep = ",")
# 2: update column names
colnames(MyData_trait1) <- c("ID","trait1")
# 3: merge to another data frame
MyData <- merge(MyData, MyData_trait1, by.x = "ID", by.y = "ID")
```

I wanted to do this in a for loop, but so far I only got it to read the files, by doing this:

```
for (trait in c("trait1","trait2","trait3","trait4",
            "trait5","trait6","trait7","trait8")){
# 1: read in files
varname <- paste("MyData_", trait, sep = "")
assign(varname, read.csv(paste0("datafile_", trait, ".csv"),header=T,sep = ","))
}
```

How do I incorporate the other two steps in this for loop?
The goal is to eventually get MyData to be a data frame of this format:

```
ID trait1 trait2 trait3 trait4 trait5 trait6 trait7 trait8 
1 .02 .04 .05 .05 .04 .04 .07 .03 
2 .04 .04 .07 .03 .02 .04 .05 .05
4 .03 .07 .05 .04 .03 .07 .05 .04
.... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) read files in

```
vars <- paste0("trait", 1:8)
files <- paste0("datafile_", vars, ".csv")
all_dat <- lapply(files, read.csv, header=TRUE)
names(all_dat) <- vars
```

(ii) insert trait name in each table, and merge all table into a single data frame (long format)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- plyr::ldply(vars, function(x) all_dat[[x]] %>% mutate(var=x))
```

(iii) convert long data frame to wide format

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% spread(var, score)
```